# In Tron: Legacy, how did Kevin Flynn recognize Rinzler as [REDACTED]?

Tags: tron, tron-legacy

This here is some padding to hide the spoiler in the question from being visible on the question page.  The question follows.

Shortly after Quorra, Kevin, and Sam get off the transport, Rinzler captures Quorra, what was it about Rinzler that made Kevin recognize him as

> Tron?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He recognized him due to his dual-wielding discs.

> Right after Kevin says, "It's him, Tron," the camera focuses on the discs in Rinzler's hands for a few seconds. It's also possible he recognized him by his clothing.  He still had the distinctive 'T' made of squares on his upper-chest.

Comment: Dual discs didn't seem like a very positive identifier (unless a bigger deal was made of that in the original), but I can see how the "T" would set him apart--hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: Might want to hide your answer as a spoiler

Comment: have to say, i never even noticed the symbol on the shirt, but there is a scene earlier which shows how the dual-wielding could have been a clue.

Comment: @Distill It didn't happen in the original.  Earlier in the movie there was a scene where he got his hands on someone else's disc in addition to his own, and he found it useful during battle.

Comment: @HorusKol Don't worry, you're not the only one.  I didn't spot it until _Tron: Uprising_ drew attention to the symbol.

Comment: Recognizing Rinzler as Tron from Rinzler’s dual-wielding discs is worse than trying to blindly identify Dolph Lundgren’s Punisher from a skull-headed knife. Tron’s 4-pixel “T” always existed, even if it was very much an understated implicit aesthetic of the original film. Rinzler shared this symbol, and that is the way their identity could be identified.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that Tron has some sort of squares on his chest, in his Tron from and same for his Rinzler form, if you see in any other costume they don't have those squares, only him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a much better answer if you could include pictures showing this design.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Flynn is the Creator of the Grid; the Grid's equivalent of the Christian
God. Now granted, he's not Rinzler's creator, but he could have been working,
and/or living with Rinzler, long enough to recognize him.

Rinzler could easily  have worked with Clu before the betrayal.
Whatever happened between the three of them, Flynn would be smart enough
to figure it out.